xslt Identity Transform Template Failing to Match (2024)
Basically the same problem described (and solved) here:
xslt Identity Transform Template Failing to Match
My XML begins with these lines
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TRANSFER xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <DATASECTION>
    <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung ID="01">
      <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text>
        <TextPos>
          <COORD>
            .....
     <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Bauwerk_Symbol>
.....

I want to make a full copy of the XML-file but I need to skip all elements "DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text". So I tried to take one of the many "identity transforms" and bumbled around:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       123
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


The xmlns comes from an online-xslt-generator
The first template with xsl:copy is taken from stackoverflow. The weird "123" is just added for testing to see what happens.
The second template with empty body should match the elements to ignore.

Current state of my work:

As software I use XMLNotepad on Windows 10
The XML is completely duplicated.
the "123" is also added.
The second template does not match anything, so the elements are not ignored. I tried different kind of "path", but no success.

I have no idea how to solve it ..

Wrong XSLT?
Wrong solution?
-(Wrong user?)

Many thanks in advance for some advices!

Default namespace on the XML elements requires your XSLT to declare a prefix for that namespace (e.g. xmlns:il="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3") and use it in pattern/expressions match="il:DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text" to select elements from that namespace.
